# I am executing system("kmsg -v time >/data/temp&"); i want the pid without using ps command

Tags: android, c, system, adb, pid

I am using this call in my C code `system("logcat -v time >/data/temp&");`
I want the pid of the process created without using `ps` command which anyways does not help because it does not start a process with the name kmsg in it.
`system("echo $!>/data/pid_file");` also does not help, it just inserts null value to /data/pid_file.
Can anyone give me a way to club these two commands. and I have used several ways to do it so please try to give a method that positively works.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you `fork` your process yourself. Then you will know the pid. In this example `child_pid` will hold your desired pid.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

-

```
pid_t child_pid = fork();

if (!child_pid) {
    // child goes here

    char * args[] = {"logcat", "-v", "time", NULL};

    int fd = open("/data/temp", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);

    if (!fd) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // map fd onto stdout
    dup2(fd, 1);

    // You will probably want to disconnect stdin and stderr
    // So we will redircet them to /dev/null
    fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
    if (!fd) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // disable stdin
    dup2(fd, 0);
    // disable stderr
    dup2(fd, 2);

    execvp(*args, args);

    // will only return if exec fails for whatever reason
    // for instance file not found

    perror("exec");

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// parent process continues here

if(child_pid == -1) {
    // can happen if you have reached process limit (ulimit -u) or are out of memory
    perror("fork");
}
```

Comment: i get what you are doing but this is not working for me but the process is not starting with this.. nor is the file being created

Comment: @user2427150 Are you getting any meaningful error messages? If the file is not being created then you must have an error occurring either during the `fork` (which I doubt) or during `open`. In either case you should get an error message through `perror`.

Comment: the error was with `open`,i just added `777` as the next argument to open and compilation error was gone, now the file is being created, now the problem which i am facing is that this process is not running in background, it exits as soon as the parent process exits, i tried `sleep(20)` in child process still it exits when the parent exits.

Comment: i am wondering if in adb shell the all child processes are killed automatically if the parent exits, and there is no concept of orphan process in this environment.

Comment: @uncreative comment out the line that disables `stderr` and see if you get a meaningful error message. Otherwise it may really be an issue with all child processes being killed in the debugging environment. If you call `wait` in the parent at the end of my code then it will wait for the child to exit.